# EmbeddedPicture & java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap

Tags: android

I'm developing music player and I use picture from audio files to display it in UI of my app, if I change music very fast (previous, next button) then I can get `java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap`, but popular players from Play market doesn't have this problem if I change music very fast. How can I avoid this error as well as in other music apps?

Similar question with the same error didn't help me

MediaService class

```
    MediaMetadataRetriever mMetaRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    mMetaRetriever.setDataSource(songPath);
    byte[] art = mMetaRetriever.getEmbeddedPicture();
    Bitmap iconUrl = null;
    try {
        if (art != null) {
            iconUrl = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(art, 0, art.length);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

UI class

```
    try {
        // with or without it error happens anyway
        /*if (mBitmap != null && !mBitmap.isRecycled()) {
            mBitmap.recycle();
            mBitmap = null;
            mLogo.setImageBitmap(null);
        }*/
        mBitmap = metadata.getBitmap(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART);
        mLogo.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

Comment: You have put two code sample. Which one are you using ? what is the error you are facing with each code sample ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just decided to use `AsyncTask` and cancel execution (`mImageViewAsync.cancel(true);`) for current instance when a new instance is created and executed, so in this case `onPostExecute` is triggered less then `doInBackground`, so now it be difficult for app to crash (but it still can in some cases, but it's not important so)

```
private ImageViewAsync mImageViewAsync;

    private void updateMetaData(MediaMetadataCompat metadata) {
        //...
        mLogo.setImageBitmap(null);
        if (mImageViewAsync != null) {
            mImageViewAsync.cancel(true);
        }

        mImageViewAsync = new ImageViewAsync();
        mImageViewAsync.execute(metadata);
    }

    private class ImageViewAsync extends AsyncTask<MediaMetadataCompat,Void,Bitmap> {

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(MediaMetadataCompat... meta) {
            return meta[0].getBitmap(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            mLogo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
```